# Making a panel draggable

Tags: c#, panel

I am creating a "cropping tool", and i need to make a panel that contains 2 buttons draggable.

Until now i've tried something like this, but the change location event happens only when i click the right button of the mouse...

```
this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(onRightClickMouse);
private void onRightClickMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
      {
            Point localMouseClickPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            panel1.Location = localMouseClickPoint;
      }
}
```

My question: How can i make that panel draggable in my form?(I mean click on the panel then drag it to a location).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
delegate void updatePanelCallback();
panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(onMouseDown);
panel1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(onMouseUp);
System.Timers.Timer runTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
runTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimerElapsed);
private void onMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        return;
    }
    runTimer.Enabled = false;
}
private void onMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    runTimer.Enabled = false;
}
public void updatePanelLocation()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new updatePanelCallback(updatePanelLocation), new object[] {});
    }
    else
    {
        Cursor curs = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        panel1.Location = curs.Position;
    }
}
private void onTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    updatePanelLocation();
}
```

Comment: I allready have a function for the left button... (selecting the area to be cropped).

Comment: @user3281950 so, what are you asking then? It seems like you're asking why it only works on right click?

Comment: Nope, i mean how to drag the panel after the mouse... Not to directly change the panel location when right click occurs.

Comment: @user3281950 There you go.

Comment: @user3281950 If you can provide errors, that would be nice.

Comment: I don't recieve any error... but it just dont works... the panel not moving.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something in two steps, preparing the action on `MouseDown` event and finishing it on `MouseUp`.